# Correcting a proof regarding Lebesgue integral.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, alternative-proof

The question and a proof I found on the internet is given below:

Suppose that $g$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R},$ let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $a \neq 0$. Prove or disprove: the function $h(x) = g(a x + b)$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R}.$

the statement is correct and here is the proof.
 Suppose that $g$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R},$ Then $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(u) \, du < \infty $ by definition. Now, define $h(x) = g(a x + b)$ for $a \neq 0.$\

Let $u = a x + b ,$ then $du = a \,dx,$ so $dx = \frac{du}{a}.$ Also, $\int_{\mathbb{R}} h(x) \,dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(a x + b) \, dx = (1/a ) \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(u) \, du,$ which is $< \infty$ by the given, so  $\int_{\mathbb{R}} h(x) \, dx $ is finite, so $h$ is integrable.

I doubt that this proof is correct from one of my previous questions , could anyone point out a hint for the correct proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT

Begin with proving this for every function $1_A(x)$ where $A$ is measurable with finite measure.

Then prove this for non-negative functions with approximation by an increasing sequence of non-negative simple functions and by using the monotone convergence theorem.

Then for the general case,apply the previous case to  $f^-,f^+$

EDIT

> Since you have proved the first two steps for simple functions then for non-negative  $f$:
>
> Exists an increasing  sequence  $h_n$ of non-negative simple functions such that $h_n \to f$ pointwise thus $g_n(ax+b) \to f(ax+b)$
>
> We have by monotone convergence:
>
> $$\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x)dx=\lim_n\int_{\Bbb{R}}h_n(x)dx=\lim_n\int_{\Bbb{R}}h_n(ax+b)dx=\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(ax+b)dx$$

Continue from here..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100417/discussion-on-answer-by-marios-gretsas-correcting-a-proof-regarding-lebesgue-int).

Comment: Can you please describe explicitly doing it for non-negative functions?

Comment: @Secretly ..no ..you asked for a hint not a complete solution...if you want you can ask another question  to show your attempt

Comment: Then what how is the a beside the x will enter the situation?

Comment: I did not understand your final question

Comment: I mean we are proving that the substitution is valid for nonnegative function now, so how will I reach $\int g(ax + b)$ is finite?

Comment: @Secretly  just approximate with monotone convergence...the other time you ask a question ,do not ask for a hint but for a complete answer..